# Javascript: Read out session id from cookie

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, browser

for websockets I have to expose my sessionid from the cookie.

I have searched a bit and found that I should be able to access cookies by:

```
console.log(document.cookie);
```

unfortunatly this doesn't work or better document.cookie contains an empty string even chrome itself shows me the cookie also authentication works.

Can it be that chrome hides the cookie for javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can happen if the server is configured to send the session cookie with [the `HttpOnly` flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie). This way the cookie becomes invisible/inaccessible to client side scripting languages like JS.

To achieve your concrete functional requirement, either reconfigure the server to not do so, or look for alternate means, e.g. setting a custom cookie (without the `HttpOnly` flag, of course), or letting the server side view technology dynamically print the current session ID as a JS variable or as an attribute of some HTML element so that JS can access it by traversing the HTML DOM.

Comment: Hi, I will need some time finding why cookie: { httpOnly: false } doesn't work in express. However your answer sounds logic. Are there any downsides on changing the httpOnly flag to false?

Comment: You can confirm in the very same Chrome cookies table if it's really `HttpOnly` or not. As to the server configuration, feel free to ask a new question. I at least have never heard of a "express" server. As to the downsides, it would only increase the risk of a successful XSS attack, but you don't need to be afraid if you properly HTML-escape any user-controlled data during redisplaying.

Comment: ok. that all I need know. Byside express is a senetra (RoR) like framework for node.js